# dev server hiccups after saving from in Django admin

Tags: django, django-forms

This is starting bug me: whenever I use the django admin to add or edit a record, I hit save and expect a confirmation page, but the result is a page that tells me the website is experiencing an error (it's not a Django page with a traceback, just a default view in my browser). If I hit reload or back in the browser, it takes me back to the user form. Even though the confimation page doesn't display, it never fails to save my entry in the database, so it's apparently just a problem generating/serving the confirmation page.

Has anyone else had this problem? Am I missing something obvious?

My server: Django dev server
My browser: Internet Explorer 7 (but same problem occurs with any broswer I use)
My OS: Windows XP

Comment: What web server? (Django dev server, Apache, ...)

Comment: Do you have either an overridden `save()` method on your model class or a `pre_save` or `post_save` signal handler registered? If so, could anything in that code be raising an exception? What about middleware -- could you have some post-request logging or response modification going on that could be causing an error at the last minute?

Also, do you get the pretty-printed error pages when an exception is raised elsewhere in your code?

Comment: I'm using the django dev server, pretty much right out of the box with no modifications, no overridden save methods or pre/post signal handlers. If I followed a simple make-your-first-blog tutorial and ran it on my dev server, I would probably get this same phenomenon when I save. I definately do get pretty-printed error messages when an exception gets raised elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

I got such a behaiviour when I overwrote `__init__` incorrectly. Or to be more precise when switching to a new version of Django with these worng `__init__`s. That was the day I started to love signals :D.

Can you post your models?

Answer (score 0):

This is certainly not how it's supposed to work! Have you been messing around in the Django codebase at all? The first thing that comes to mind here is a "pdb.set_trace()" left by mistake somewhere in the change_list codepath. Off-hand I can't think what else would cause the server to simply not respond.

Comment: Nope, haven't messed with the codebase (that's beyond me).  You know it's wierd, the server responds ok if I reload the page or go back in my browser, but it's just that initial submit that seems to missfire. I wish I knew more about how the server works. And it does this on both my work computer and my home computer.